# R Shiny: eventReactive with two controls

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following R Shiny code:

```
  economics_points <- eventReactive(input$sigmaThresholdSlider, {
    print("input$sigmaThresholdSlider fired.")
    get_points(input$daterange, 1, input$sigmaThresholdSlider)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  economics_points <- eventReactive(input$daterange, {
    print("input$daterange fired.")
    get_points(input$daterange, 1, input$sigmaThresholdSlider)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
```

The problem is that `economics_points` is only updated when the `daterange` control is changed, not when the `sigmaThresholdSlider` control is changed.  If I reverse the order of the two statements, `economics_points` is only updated when `sigmaThresholdSlider` is moved.  In other words, the second statement overrides the first.

How do I change this code so that it runs when *either* control is adjusted?

The [documentation](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/observeEvent.html) says that the `eventExpr` argument of `eventReactive` can be "even a complex expression inside curly braces", but no helpful examples are given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need `eventReactive` here - you could just use `reactive`, and it will respond to either value changing.

```
economics_points <- reactive(get_points(input$daterange, 1, input$sigmaThresholdSlider))
```

EDIT: not sure how to handle the `ignoreNULL = FALSE` bit, though, doesn't seem to be an option with `reactive`.

Answer (score 5):

By giving a list it seems to work:

#### Server

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  view <- eventReactive(list(input$t1, input$t2),{
      t1 <- input$t1              
      t2 <- input$t2

      rnorm(1)
  })

  output$view <- renderPrint(view())

})
```

#### ui

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage( 

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("t1", "t1"),
      actionButton("t2", "t2")
    ),


    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("view")
    )
  )
))
```